# Crickets found in Wales?

Tags: forest

Can we find crickets in Northern Wales? If no, what other insects found in Northern Wales make a chirping sound like that of crickets?

If this isn't an appropriate question for this thread, please migrate it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a specific problem in entomology which doesn't fall within the purview of Earth Science SE.

Comment: Well, where do I take this question to then?

Comment: http://biology.stackexchange.com/ seems like the natural place for this

Answer (score 3):

There are crickets species living in Wales ([Reference](http://www.northwaleswildlifetrust.org.uk/wildlife/species-explorer/animal/invertebrates/grasshoppers-and-crickets))

- Field Grasshopper
- Green Grasshopper
- Meadow Grasshopper
- Roesel's Bush-cricket
- Oak Bush-cricket
- Speckled Bush-cricket
- Mottled Grasshopper

  and even if a species is not common in this part of the UK it might be brought there e.g. as a secret passanger in a car.